# pthread in C : i can't figure why pthread_cond_signal is not waking up one thread

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, pthreads

I want a routine to be done by multiple threads, once they are created they need their work to be all finished before copying their calculated things. So a thread is on cond_wait once it has its work done.

A piece of code that works now:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define MAX_RAYCAST_THREADS 2

typedef struct      s_thread_env
{
    int             id;
    pthread_t       thread;
    int             work_done;
    void            *shared_data;
}                   t_thread_env;

typedef struct      s_shared_data
{
    t_thread_env    *tab_thread_env;
    int             max_thread;
    int             all_work_done;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_cond_t  cond;
    int             stop;
}                   t_shared_data;

void    set_threads_again(int id, t_shared_data *shared_data)
{
    int i;

    shared_data->all_work_done = 0;
    i = -1;
    while (++i < shared_data->max_thread)
        shared_data->tab_thread_env[i].work_done = 0;
    //i = -1;
    //while (++i < shared_data->max_thread)
    //{
        //if (i != id)
        //{
            //printf("cond_signal to thread %i\n", i);
            //pthread_cond_signal(&shared_data->cond);
        //}
    //}
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&shared_data->cond);
}

void    wait_or_signal(t_thread_env *thread_env, t_shared_data *shared_data)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (i < shared_data->max_thread && shared_data->tab_thread_env[i].work_done)
        i++;
    if (i == shared_data->max_thread)
    {
        printf("    allworkdone sent by thread %i\n", thread_env->id);
        //printf("      copy_screenpixels() by thread %i\n", thread_env->id);

        set_threads_again(thread_env->id, shared_data);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("    thread number %i is waiting for other threads\n", thread_env->id);
        pthread_cond_wait(&shared_data->cond, &shared_data->mutex);
        printf("ENFIN ! thread number %i woke up from condwait\n", thread_env->id);
    }
}

void    *routine(void *arg)
{
    t_thread_env    *thread_env;
    t_shared_data   *shared_data;
    int             stop;

    thread_env = (t_thread_env *)arg;
    shared_data = (t_shared_data *)thread_env->shared_data;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&shared_data->mutex);
    while (!shared_data->stop)
    {
        printf("new frame> thread_id = %i, thread_env->work_done = %i\n", thread_env->id, thread_env->work_done);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&shared_data->mutex);
        printf("        raycast() in routine thread %i\n", thread_env->id);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&shared_data->mutex);
        thread_env->work_done++;
        wait_or_signal(thread_env, shared_data);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&shared_data->mutex);
    return (0);
}

void    init_thread_env(t_shared_data *shared_data, int i)
{
    t_thread_env    *thread_env;

    thread_env = &shared_data->tab_thread_env[i];
    thread_env->id = i;
    thread_env->shared_data = shared_data;
    if (pthread_create(&thread_env->thread, NULL, routine, thread_env) != 0)
        printf("Error pthread_create for %i\n", i);
}

void    free_all(t_shared_data *shared_data)
{
    int i;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&shared_data->mutex);
    shared_data->stop = 1;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&shared_data->mutex);
    i = -1;
    while (++i < shared_data->max_thread)
        pthread_join(shared_data->tab_thread_env[i].thread, NULL);
    printf("\nEND\n\n");
    //free etc
}

int     main()
{
    int             i;
    t_shared_data   *shared_data;

    shared_data = (t_shared_data*)malloc(sizeof(t_shared_data)); // if (!shared data){free etc}
    shared_data->max_thread = MAX_RAYCAST_THREADS;
    pthread_mutex_init(&shared_data->mutex, 0);
    pthread_cond_init(&shared_data->cond, 0);
    shared_data->tab_thread_env = (t_thread_env*)malloc(sizeof(t_thread_env) * shared_data->max_thread);
    i = -1;
    while (++i < shared_data->max_thread)
        init_thread_env(shared_data, i);
    while (1)
        sleep(1); //program is turning
    free_all(shared_data);
    return (0);
}
```

The correct output:

```
new frame> thread_id = 0, thread_env->work_done = 0
                raycast() in routine thread 0
        thread number 0 is waiting for other threads
new frame> thread_id = 1, thread_env->work_done = 0
                raycast() in routine thread 1
        allworkdone sent by thread 1
cond_signal to thread 0
new frame> thread_id = 1, thread_env->work_done = 0
ENFIN ! thread number 0 woke up from condwait
new frame> thread_id = 0, thread_env->work_done = 0
                raycast() in routine thread 0
        thread number 0 is waiting for other threads
                raycast() in routine thread 1
        allworkdone sent by thread 1
cond_signal to thread 0
new frame> thread_id = 1, thread_env->work_done = 0
ENFIN ! thread number 0 woke up from condwait
new frame> thread_id = 0, thread_env->work_done = 0
                raycast() in routine thread 0
        thread number 0 is waiting for other threads
                raycast() in routine thread 1
```

Thank you for reading me, have a good day!

EDIT: I made a more readable and compilable version with only 1 mutex (old version: https://pastebin.com/4zMyBJi2).

EDIT2: deleted some parts of the original post, and tried to avoid every data races, my code still has some (as it still does not work). But I think I am close to get something working

EDIT3: Ok it is working now, I edited the code. The main issue was my disastrous use of the shared_data variables.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your question and how to create a [mcve]. The "threads are created using" snippet is not enough, not to mention that it unconditionally creates only a single thread and where `e` will point to the very last element in the `tab` array (or perhaps out of bounds, depending on `tab` and how it was defined/initialized).

Comment: ok thank you, i am trying to put a minimal reproductible example!

Comment: NB : yes i copied from code but from different lines (i tried to minimalize lol) and i just made a not functional code result, in the pthread_create part. I will edit after I try to do a minimal reproductible example for myself, and if i still have troubles i will put it there

Comment: In order to ensure that all threads see `multithread->all_work_done = 1;`, you should hold the mutex while you do this, I think.

Comment: ok i put some mutex everywhere

Comment: The `wait_or_signal` function modifies `shared_data->all_work_done` without holding the mutex that's supposed to protect the shared data. So long as you have any code that accesses or modifies shared data without holding the appropriate mutex, your code will *never* be reliable. Also, `set_threads_again` sets `all_work_done` to zero *last*. That's not right -- the other threads may already have done everything. You need to do that *first*.

Comment: Thank you, now it works as intended!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to make my raycasting threads work using *1 call of
> pthread_create for each thread* (in an initialisation function). **Is
> it possible to do it?**

Each successful call to `pthread_create` creates exactly one thread, so this is the *only* way to do it.  But do not get confused between threads' start functions and threads themselves.  Multiple threads can be created to run the same thread function, but this requires multiple calls to `pthread_create`, one for each thread.

> I guess it is better (for performances) to do
> it in this way (rather than an enormous amount of pthread_create and
> pthread_join calls), **is this correct?**

Having chosen to use a certain number of threads to do certain pieces of work, the number of `pthread_create` calls is already determined.  If you have performance concerns then they should be about how many threads to use, the details of the work they are to perform, and the nature and granularity of their synchronization.

> In order to make it happen, the last thread (number n) to finish his
> job has to tell the other ones that every thread has finished, so
> there is a pthread_cond_wait for the (n - 1) first threads, and the
> last thread (number n) calls pthread_cond_signal for each (n - 1)
> first ones. Each thread has his own mutex.

That seems a little overkill, even if you can make it technically correct.  It doesn't make much sense to have a mutex per thread, because **mutexes are useful only when different threads use the same one**.  It may make sense to have different mutexes for protecting different shared resources, however.  You would probably want CVs for some of those, but not all of them.

This appears to be (at least one area) where your code is failing.  Your threads are not properly synchronized because they all rely on *different* mutexes to protect *the same* resources.  It's not clear to me whether it makes sense for your program to have any more than just one mutex, but I would start by reducing your usage to that.

Comment: I updated the code in the question post, it is now compilable. I tried with 1 mutex, but the output is quite disturbing because it doesn't go to `printf("ENFIN ! thread number %i woke up from condwait\n", thread_id);` until the very end of the program, but it is still woke up

Comment: ok i just figured that it doesn't print a lot, but it prints more than only 1 time

Comment: @BretzelLudique, your update to the question reveals that your code is (still) full of data races.  Any time any of your threads accesses an object shared among the threads, even just to read it, that must be done with the (same) mutex held locked, unless the object being accessed is assigned its value before any of threads are created and never modified during the lifetime of any of them.

Comment: As a separate matter, instead of signaling the CV n - 1 times, consider using a single `pthread_cond_broadcast()` to wake *all* threads then waiting on the CV.